# Retain string up to second slash in regex?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to **only retain** the string after the first section of characters (which includes - and numerics) but before the forward slash.

I have the following string:

```
x <- c('/youtube.com/videos/cats', '/google.com/images/dogs', 'bbc.com/movies')

/youtube.com/videos/cats
/google.com/images/dogs
bbc.com/movies
```

So it would look like this

```
/youtube.com/
/google.com/
bbc.com/
```

For reference I am using R 3.6

I have tried positive lookbehinds and the closest I got was this: `^\/[^\/]*`

Any help appreciated

So in the `bbc.com/movies` example - the string does not start with a forward slash / but I still want to be able to keep the `bbc.com` part during the match

Comment: your attempt was close, you can do `gsub('(^/?[^/]*/)|.', '\\1', x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `sub` here to only perform a single regex replacement:

```r
sub('^(/?[^/]*/).*', '\\1', x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DbUJQG/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
  -`(/?[^/]*/)` - Capturing group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern): an optional `/`, then 0 or more chars other than `/` and then a `/`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars, as many as possible.

See [an R test online](https://ideone.com/qmd9hp):

```r
test <- c("/youtube.com/videos/cats", "/google.com/images/dogs", "bbc.com/movies")
sub('^(/?[^/]*/).*', '\\1', test)
# => [1] "/youtube.com/" "/google.com/"  "bbc.com/"
```

Comment: Is it possible to capture upto the second grouping too? so upto but including the 3rd slash if it exists ? e.g. youtube.com/cats/dogs/beans would capture youtube.com/cats/dogs/ only?

Comment: @BeansOnToast `^(/?[^/]*(?:/[^/]*){2}).*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DbUJQG/2).

Answer (score 1):

First great username. Try this, you can leverage the fact str_extract only pulls the first match out. assuming all urls match letters.letters this pattern should work. Let me know if you have numbers in any of them.

```
library(stringr) 
c("/youtube.com/videos/cats",
  "/google.com/images/dogs",
  "bbc.com/movies") %>% 
   str_extract(., "/?\\w+\\.\\w+/")
```

produces

```
"/youtube.com/" "/google.com/"  "bbc.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R

```
gsub('(\\/?.*\\.com\\/).*', '\\1', x)
[1] "/youtube.com/" "/google.com/"  "bbc.com/"
```

Answer (score -1):

an alternative would be with the rebus Package:

```
library(rebus)
library(stringi)

t <-  c("/youtube.com/videos/cats"," /google.com/images/dogs"," bbc.com/movie")

 pattern <- zero_or_more("/") %R% one_or_more(ALPHA) %R% DOT %R% one_or_more(ALPHA) %R% zero_or_more("/")

 stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(t, pattern) 

[1] "/youtube.com/" "/google.com/"  "bbc.com/"
```